Amazon EventBridge pattern for Appflow events
I want to create EventBridge rule to match "AppFlow End Flow Run Report" event type, but I'm running into problems, I'm new to AWS so it's very possible that I'm missing something basic.
EventBridge offers AppFlow event patterns for the following AppFlow event types.

AppFlow Event Flow Deactivated
AppFlow Event Flow Report
AppFlow Scheduled Flow Deactivated
AppFlow Start Flow Run Report
AppFlow End Flow Run Report


I don't see "EndFlow" eventName in CloudTrail Event history at all. I only see "RunFlow" events. I read that EventBridge reads CloudTrail Events, to match against the rule. I have created new trail with Management events: Enabled, Data events: Read & Write Enabled.

Since I can't find "EndFlow" I decided to try instead the "RunFlow" event. But it looks like EventBridge's sample event pattern for "AppFlow Run Flow Run Report" event type in EventBridge does not match events I see in the CloudTrail's Event history. Testing default EventBridge pattern for "AppFlow Start Flow Run Report" event type does not match any "RunFlow" events either.


This is a sample event suggested by EventBridge
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "x",
  "detail-type": "AppFlow End Flow Run Report",
  "source": "aws.appflow",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2020-08-30T12:26:13Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources": [],
  "detail": {
    "flow-name": "<Name of the Flow>",
    "created-by": "<User who created the flow >",
    "flow-arn": "<ARN of the flow>",
    "start-time": "<Start time stamp of the flow run >",
    "end-time": "<Time stamp of the completion of the flow run>",
    "source": "<Source Connector>/<Connector-Profile>",
    "destination": "<Destination Connector>/<Connector-Profile>",
    "source-object": "<Name of the source object>",
    "destination-object": "<Name of the destination object>",
    "trigger-type": "<OnDemand | Event | Scheduled>",
    "incremental-transfer-time-range": {
      "schedule-start-time": "<start time stamps for incremental scheduled pull>",
      "schedule-end-time": "<end time stamps for incremental scheduled pull>"
    },
    "status": "<Status of the flow run: Success or failure>",
    "error": "<Error message if the flow run failed.>",
    "num-of-records-processed": "<Count of records processed>",
    "num-of-records-filtered": " <Count of records filtered>",
    "num-of-record-failures": "<Count of records failed during processing>",
    "data-processed": "<Total volume in KB of data processed in the flow run>"
  }
}

and this is what I see when I view CloudTrail Event history for "RunFlow" event
{
        "eventTime": "2024-09-03T00:48:43Z",
        "eventSource": "appflow.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "RunFlow",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "141.156.139.14",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "requestParameters": {
            "flowName": "email-flow"
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "executionId": "x"
        },
        "requestID": "x",
        "eventID": "x",
        "readOnly": false,
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
        "managementEvent": true,
        "recipientAccountId": "x",
        "eventCategory": "Management"
    }

I'm confused why does "source": "aws.appflow" in the sample event does not match "eventSource": "appflow.amazonaws.com" in the actual event in the CloudTrail. What am I missing? When I try use default EventBridge suggestion for

Alternatively it looks like I can possibly track AppFlow Metric "FlowExecutionSucceeded" via CloudWatch instead. Is this the correct approach? Any suggestions what would a pattern look like for a rule in EventBridge to track "FlowExecutionsSucceeded" Metric from CloudWatch?

